# NodeJS can't see LESS although it was installed with global opition

Tags: css, node.js, less, require

I installed nodejs
I installed npm
I installed less with `-g` option

but when I run nodejs via console and write command `less`, there is:

```
ReferenceError: less is not defined
    at repl:1:2
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
```

I can run `less` or `lessc`, but outside nodejs

to answer for replies:

```
var less = require('less');
Error: Cannot find module 'less'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at repl:1:12
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at repl.js:249:20
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

I need it for Assetic Symfony2

And when I try to do assetic:dump via symfony2 console I have the same error what I have when I do it by running it in nodejs "enviroment"...

Comment: How about running `var less = require('less');` within node?

Answer (score 1):

You need to require the module:

```
var less = require('less')
```

http://lesscss.org/#usage has a sample in node (search for subsection Usage in Code):

```
var less = require('less');

less.render('.class { width: (1 + 1) }', function (e, css) {
    console.log(css);
});
```

Comment: Ok, I understand, but tell how can I config node and less to work with symfony2 assetic?

Comment: @kspacja can you install locally (npm install less) and then try?

Comment: No, will it change sth?

Comment: That error is saying that node can't find the module. If you install locally and it does find the module, then your node path is messed up.